# use bold font at coding side in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

hii friend i have one problem please try to solve this

```
msg.Body = "Hi , " + txtrfname.Text.Trim() + "!\n" + " Your RCNO is " + rcno + "!\n Thank you for showning intrasted and registration Please <a href='" + activationurl + "'>click hear to activate </a> your account and enjoy our services \n Thank you.";
```

i have this code in c# scripting language and now i want to bold "rcno" in this code becouse when user get this email they can see look like this
"Hi , bhavesh Your RCNO is **1234** Thank you for showning intrasted and registration Please click hear to activate  your account and enjoy our services \n Thank you.";

hear i want 1234 in bold,
so how can i do it in coding??

Comment: [<strong>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) ...

Answer (score 3):

Use [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong):

```
msg.Body = "Hi , " + txtrfname.Text.Trim() + "!\n" + 
   " Your RCNO is <strong>" + rcno + "</strong>!\n Thank you for 
   showning intrasted and registration Please <a href='" + activationurl + 
   "'>click hear to activate </a> your account and enjoy our services \n Thank you.";
```

> The HTML Strong Element `<strong>` gives text strong importance, and is typically displayed in bold.

---

**Side Note:**

Another possibility is to use `<b>`. See the difference [here](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/strong-and-b-elements.htm).

Comment: Should be using `<strong>` instead of `<b>`.